# Contacts API for web.de and GMX

Tags: api, developer-tools

I'm working on a project where I have to import contacts from GMX and web.de. I search for one on their website for developer api but I cannot find any reference document. Are these websites provide any developer api? I see Xing.com uses these services for importing contacts and I believe they must not be using any screen scraping methods. Can some body point me to the right direction please? I appreciate your help.